# How to load filepath from resource folder when running through jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, file, jar, ide

While loading some file path from resource folder to use in the program I am using like

"src/resource/filename"

I have even tried

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
String file = (classLoader.getResource(fileName)).getFile();
```

But its giving incorrect path both in IDE and JAR

Comment: How are you building your application? are you using maven, gradle, or similar tools?

Comment: i am using Maven tool for building

Comment: try using an unzip tool to view the internal structure of your jar and see where the file is located

Comment: If you are using maven classpath resources should be in `src\main\resources` folder not `src\resource` folder.